# Creating PowerShell Script templates for easy group management

Tags: powershell, active-directory, usergroups

First of all thanks for the help to the other users, because of that I learned a lot.

I have a problem that there are lots of user templates in my company (Lots of different group settings depending operation). Because of that I want to make it easy for my colleges to assign user to Operations.

I think about a solution that My colleges enter the user and Group to a CSV file, then the script goes trough the CSV lines, detects the Operation, and go to the operations TXT file to get the group info, then add the user.
The files are:
UserAndOperation.csv and it includes 2 columns, first one is user second one is Operation
Then the TXT files are added, in them the Groups are added for every line (I also wanted to make only one Operation csv that first column is operation name and the second one is groups that has to be added, and separated by "," but that scared my eye :D ).

this is the Frankenstein code that I created:

```
Import-Csv ".\UserAndOperation.csv" | ForEach-Object {get-aduser $_.User | if($_.Operation = "Operation1"){
        $Groups = Get-Content .\operation1.txt
        foreach($group in $groups)
        {Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_.User -MemberOf $Group}
    }
elseif ($_.Operaiton = "Operation2"){
        $Groups = Get-Content .\operation2.txt
        foreach($group in $groups)
        {Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_.User -MemberOf $Group}
    }

And goes for each operation
}
```

It gives an error that it don't recognize the if and elseif statements.

I don't know how to proceed, could anyone help me with fixing it ?

Thanks and best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pipe results into an if statement.
e.g.

```
get-aduser $_.User | if($_.Operation
```

You also have a typo in:

```
$_.Operaiton
```

I would suggest to clean up the code a bit by trying to put statements one per line, so as to not confuse yourself, outputting debug statements, etc..

Answer (score 0):

As has [already been pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65998701/712649), you can't shove arbitrary control flow statements like `if` into the middle of a pipeline statement.

Beyond that, your intended `if/else` approach will mean a lot of *repeated code*, making the script harder to maintain.

You could use a hashtable (`@{}`) to "map" the operation name to the relevant file name, this way you only need to write the loop to add the group memberships *once*:

```
# map the Operation column value to the relevant file path
$operations = @{
  'Operation1' = 'path\to\operation1.txt'
  'Operation2' = 'path\to\operation2.txt'
  'Operation3' = 'path\to\operation3.txt'
}

Import-Csv ".\UserAndOperation.csv" | ForEach-Object {
  $User = Get-ADUser $_.User
  $Groups = Get-Content $operations[$_.Operation]
  foreach($Group in $Groups){
    Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $User -MemberOf $Group
  }
}
```